# Conditional lazy loading import timeago languages in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a multilingual reactjs app, i need to conditionaly import the used language (declared in the html and used as props, for example if i declare data-locale="nl" i need to import the dutchStrings) i have tried the if condition but it's not working because you can't do it to import files/packages!

```
import TimeAgo from 'react-timeago';
if (locale === 'en') {
  import englishStrings from 'react-timeago/lib/language-strings/en';
} else if (locale === 'nl') {
  import dutchStrings from 'react-timeago/lib/language-strings/nl';
} else {
  import frenchStrings from 'react-timeago/lib/language-strings/fr';
}
import buildFormatter from 'react-timeago/lib/formatters/buildFormatter';
```

The declared language should be in the buildFormatter so i can use it in my JSX, i have this switch condition to choose the right Strings

```
const locale = root_el.getAttribute("data-locale");

let langStrings;
switch(locale) {
  case 'en': {
    langStrings = englishStrings;
    break;
  }
  case 'nl': {
    langStrings = dutchStrings;
    break;
  }
  default:
    langStrings = frenchStrings;
}
const formatter = buildFormatter(langStrings);
```

Any sugestions/hints on how to do this correctly? do i need the switch condition?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lazy loading](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) to import components/modules conditionally, lazy loading also is a good step in performance improvements. But in order to use it, you'd have to assign it to a variable/constant so that it is recognizable outside the scope of its block. 
You could try doing something like this:

```
import TimeAgo from 'react-timeago';
import React from 'react';
let langString;
if (locale === 'en') {
  langString = React.lazy(()=>import('react-timeago/lib/language-strings/en'));
} else if (locale === 'nl') {
  langString = React.lazy(()=> import('react-timeago/lib/language-strings/nl'));
} else {
  langString = React.lazy(()=>import('react-timeago/lib/language-strings/fr'));
}
```

Depending on the condition, an appropriate module is loaded into the `langString` variable.

Comment: Tks, i think something is missing!
import frenchStrings from 'react-timeago/lib/language-strings/fr i dont see the frenchStrings or dutchStrings in the react lazy import so i can put it in the buildFormatter

Comment: You should put `langString` instead of dutchStrings or frenchStrings, as `langString` holds one module import at a time because it is a conditional import. Meaning only 1 language string module is assigned to `langString`.

Comment: I did, but i think the buildFormatter from 'react-timeago/lib/formatters/buildFormatter' is not working (const formatter = buildFormatter(langString))
before i used to put the frenchStrings or dutchStrings to get the right lang

Comment: Could you `console.log(langString)` and check what you're getting?

Comment: function u(u) {
if (t || (t = n()).then(function (n) {
    e = n.default || n;
}, function (n) {
    r = n;
}), r) throw r;
if (!e) throw t;
return Object(preact__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["createElement"])(e, u);
}
return u.displayName = "Lazy", u.__f = !0, u;